# Why is this function taking so long to evaluate?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make a function that records a few strings to a logfile on a server.  For some reason, this function takes forever to run through..about 20 seconds before it will return the Exception.   I think it's the try: statement with the file open command.

Any ideas how I can do this correctly?

```
def writeUserRecord():
    """ Given a path, logs user name, fetch version, and time"""
    global fetchVersion
    global fetchHome
    filename = 'users.log'
    logFile = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(fetchHome, filename))
    timeStamp = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
    userID = getpass.getuser()
    try:
        file = open(logFile, 'a')
        file.write('{}  {}  {}'.format(userID, timeStamp, fetchVersion))
        file.close()
    except IOError:
        print('Error Accessing Log File')
        pass
```

Comment: try except shouldn't be that slow, I think you should add a finial that hold the file.close() statement, so that no matter what happens, the file will always be closed.

Comment: That sounds like it's timing out because you can't access the file. Check your permissions.

Comment: from where will you get the global fetchVersion
    global fetchHome

Comment: better use timeit to check which function is getting long to complete

Comment: The problem is obviously on a level below your program: OS, network, server...

Comment: Could you please `raise` the exception in your `except` block and paste traceback here?

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone.  It did appear that that network drive was indeed down last night unexpectedly.  I am still confused because I thought the exception would kick in a lot quicker.